# Percent encoding a non extended ascii char like extended chars

Tags: encode, urlencode, url-encoding, unicode-escapes, percent-encoding

If we percent encode the char "€", we will have %E2%82%AC as result. Ok!

My problem:

a = %61
I already know it.

Is it possible to encode "a" to something like %XX%XX or %XX%XX%XX?
If yes, will browsers and servers understand the result as the char "a"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> If we percent encode the char "€", we will have %E2%82%AC as result.

`€` is Unicode codepoint `U+20AC EURO SIGN`. The byte sequence `0xE2 0x82 0xAC` is how U+20AC is encoded in UTF-8.  `%E2%82%AC` is the URL encoding of those bytes.

> a = %61
>   I already know it.

For ASCII character `a`, aka Unicode codepoint `U+0061 LATIN SMALL LETTER A`, that is correct.  It is encoded as byte `0x61` in UTF-8 (and most other charsets), and thus can be encoded as `%61` in URLs.

> Is it possible to encode "a" to something like %XX%XX or %XX%XX%XX?

Yes.  *Any* character can be encoded using percent encoding in a URL.  Simply encode the character in the appropriate charset, and then percent-encode the resulting bytes.  However, most ASCII non-reserved characters do not require such encoding, just use them as-is.

> If yes, will browsers and servers understand the result as the char "a"?

In URLs and URL-like content encodings (like `application/x-www-webform-urlencoded`), yes.

Comment: Thanks for your response. But what I need is the LATIN SMALL LETTER A encoded with more than one percent, like this %12%34 = "a".

Comment: Why? There is no multi-byte encoding for codepoint U+0061 in UTF-8 or most other charsets. You would have to encode codepoints in the URL using UTF-16 or UTF-32 instead, in which case `a` would be encoded as `%61%00` (UTF-16LE), `%00%61` (UTF-16LE), `%61%00%00%00` (UTF-32LE) or `%00%00%00%61` (UTF-32BE).  Otherwise, `a` is encoded as just `%61` in UTF-8 and most other charsets. What are you trying to accomplish by doing something different?